# Exception Dts is not declared

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm getting this (Dts is not declared) exception when I try to build my SSIS script task. Any idea how to resolve it?

here is the part of my code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime


    Public Class ScriptMain
        Public Sub Main()
            Try
                Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections.Add("FTP")
                cm.Properties("ServerName").SetValue(cm, Dts.Variables("SFTPServerName").Value.ToString)
                cm.Properties("ServerUserName").SetValue(cm, Dts.Variables("SFTPLogin").Value.ToString)
                cm.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(cm, Dts.Variables("SFTPPassword").Value.ToString)
                cm.Properties("ServerPort").SetValue(cm, Dts.Variables("SFTPPortNumber").Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Add `Your_Variable` in the script component. (Right click --> Edit --> Script --> ReadOnlyVariables).
2. `Dim variableString As String = Me.ReadOnlyVariables("User::Your_Variable").Value.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `me.Connections` and `me.Variables`